# Serialize and jquery object

Tags: jquery, serialization

I tried to use a jquery object to serialize some of  values in a form.  I tried using a div id that surrounded the fields I needed like this:

`var test = $("#div_tab1").serialize()`  and it was empty

```
var test = $("#form1").serialize() worked.
```

shouldn't the first example work?

I am using version 1.6.4

Answer (score 2):

> *"shouldn't the first example work?"*

No, you need to call it on a form, or on a set of input elements.

Answer (score 0):

`serialize` works only on a `form` or `form` elements.

Answer (score 0):

From [the API](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> `.serialize()`:
>
> **Description**: Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.

Notice how it says **form elements**

`.serialize()` returns a string that is meant to be placed in URLs: `?bar=baz&foo2=bar`.

It won't make sense for a non-form element, as it doesn't have a `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found that serialize works on a form or a jQuery of :input tags, but not a div that contains :input tags.

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not want to serialize the whole form, you can serialize elements within a specific #id or even a specific element name.

```
// serialize input elements within a specific #id
$('#id :input').serialize();


// serialize a specific element in the form
$('input[name=inputName]').serialize();
```